# How can I set a footer property in JSON export of DataTable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

There is a footer property in datatable which export the footer data

```
{
                    extend: 'csv',
                    footer: true,
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
```

footer : true, property allows to export footer data to csv file.

How can I set this same property in below code

```
{
                text: 'JSON',
                action: function ( e, dt, button, config ) {
                    var data = dt.buttons.exportData();
 
                    $.fn.dataTable.fileSave(
                        new Blob( [ JSON.stringify( data ) ] ),
                        'Export.json'
                    );
                }
            }
```

Is this possible ? Please help me any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is absurd. A footer in a JSON === invalid JSON.

Comment: Then why this footer: true works in all other exports like csv, excel, pdf, why its not allowing footer data not to export to json data ? @davidkonard